# Why is std::bitset<8> 4 bytes big?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

It seems for std::bitset<1 to 32>, the size is set to 4 bytes.  For sizes 33 to 64, it jumps straight up to 8 bytes.  There can't be any overhead because std::bitset<32> is an even 4 bytes.

I can see aligning to byte length when dealing with bits, but why would a bitset need to align to word length, especially for a container most likely to be used in situations with a tight memory budget?

This is under VS2010.

Comment: Considering this is 2011, I wouldn't call the max 3 wasted bytes exactly a memory concern.

Comment: It's not a memory concern if you've only got one of them.

Comment: @Jon, JB - That's the problem, it wouldn't be a concern for just one.  But I'm using bitset as a mask inside an octree, which compounds the lost 3 bytes a few ten thousand times over.

Comment: So you lose a few tens of kilobytes, then? Yeah, I can see how that'd be a problem. ;) Are you really memory-constrained? Are you willing to sacrifice faster access to the bitset in order to save those few bytes?

Comment: @jaif - I wasn't aware that this was for speed, which I can totally accept!  As for how much memory is lost, my calculator puts it at 1.5 megabytes.  Which is nothing even still, but I'm too neurotic to let it slide.  orz

Comment: @jalf: does it matter whether or not the questioner, specifically, has run out of memory yet? Even if not, it's still worth knowing roughly how far your code can scale, what's going to stop it, and why. If this thing occupies 4 bytes when it could occupy 1, then in any situation where it's the major proportion of your data, then it's as if you have down to 1/4 as much memory available as you actually do. The difference between using, say 1GB of memory vs 4GB isn't trivial, even though the difference between using 1.5MB and 0.4MB is.

Comment: Actually, I'll answer my own question - it matters if the questioner is thinking of changing his code (he shouldn't). It doesn't affect the fact that *if* you have a lot of data, *then* very small `bitset` instances isn't an efficient way to store it. It just affects the issue of whether the questioner has a lot of data ;-)

Comment: @Steve: absolutely. But it's also worth keeping a sense of perspective. At the end of the day, it's worth remembering that 30KB or 1.5MB is *nothing* on a modern PC. Asking where the memory goes, or why the tradeoff is made is absolutely a valid question, but it's important to remind oneself that *in practice it's not really going to make a difference in my memory budget*.

Comment: @jalf: hmm, I frequently do write programs that occupy a GB or two of memory, so to me this kind of overhead is a clear and present danger that I have to be aware of so I know when to avoid it. Thrashing the page file does *not* improve performance, even if word vs byte access does! It's possible that this has given me a warped perspective, not applicable to programmers writing what by comparison can only be considered "toy" apps that fit in a measly few hundred MB ;-p

Comment: @Steve: If your program occupies a GB or two, how is that a reason to be concerned about 1.5MB? Shouldn't that tell you that there are bigger fish to fry?  My point is that the person writing the code was able to work out that he loses around 1.5MB to this. That is not something you need to be concerned about whether your app takes a few hundred or 2-3GB. The whole "premature optimization" thing applies to memory too. Find out where you lose the memory that's actually significantly bloating up your app, rather than attacking a small side problem that might save you 1MB.

Comment: @jalf: possibly I'm accusing you of agreeing with Jon ("I wouldn't call this exactly a memory concern") when you don't. I agree that 1.5MB isn't something to worry about on a PC. By "this kind of overhead", I meant 4 bytes per record instead of 1, I didn't mean the 1.5MB total, sorry for being unclear. So, I think that 300% bloat is something to know about even though it's currently 300% on 0.4MB, because that bloat is *potentially* going to be the difference between 1GB and 4GB, in a different program, somewhere down the line. At that point, you'd need tighter packing than `bitset` gives.

Comment: @Steve: I think we agree. My point is just that yes, when you observe that something uses 4 times as much memory as necessary, you should investigate. But if that investigation shows that "I'm only wasting 1.5MB total", then it's probably not worth panicking over. Then it's important to step back and reevaluate how serious the issue really is, to avoid wasting your time (when there are probably far more beneficial memory optimizations that you could be focusing on instead)

Comment: @Steve, jalf - Not to jump into this, but the reason mostly I'm trying to fix this, is because the bitset itself is being used to flag redundant data, and compress it.  Uncompressed, it would require a floor of 1.1 gb.  With it, so far, I've managed to get a test set as low as 80 mb. So it definitely works.  But if something is getting wasted, may as well take care of it while you're in the neighborhood.  (I fixed it already, just had to move the bitset up one layer in my octree, where it could manage 8*8 flags instead of just 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that indexing into the bitset is done by grabbing a 32-bit value and then isolating the relevant bit because this is fastest in terms of processor instructions (working with smaller-sized values is slower on x86). The two indexes needed for this can also be calculated very quickly:

```
int wordIndex = (index & 0xfffffff8) >> 3;
int bitIndex = index & 0x7;
```

And then you can do this, which is also very fast:

```
int word = m_pStorage[wordIndex];
bool bit = ((word & (1 << bitIndex)) >> bitIndex) == 1;
```

Also, a maximum waste of 3 bytes per bitset is not exactly a memory concern IMHO. Consider that a bitset is already the most efficient data structure to store this type of information, so you would have to evaluate the waste as a percentage of the total structure size.

For 1025 bits this approach uses up 132 bytes instead of 129, for 2.3% overhead (and this goes down as the bitset site goes up). Sounds reasonable considering the likely performance benefits.

Comment: The bitset is being used inside a large octree is why this is a problem is all.  But I can accept the reasoning behind this if it's for the sake of efficiency.  I'll just modify my octree to fit the restrictions.  Thank you!

Comment: And for 3 bits, it uses 4 bytes instead of 1, for 300% overhead. So really it's a question of whether this thing constitutes a significant proportion of your total data. It's the same as when profiling performance -- it doesn't matter how long your function takes, it matters what proportion of total time all the calls to it take. If a call takes 4ms instead of 1ms, that's a negligible amount of time and not exactly a performance concern (it's not like I have time to go make a cup of coffee in 3ms). Write a program that calls this function a few million times, things change.

Comment: @SteveJessop: What is your point though? For so few bits everyone would stuff them directly into a `long` and call it a day. I picked 1025 because it sounded reasonable while still being "small" (to show a far-from-best-case scenario). At the end of the day, the question was "why?", not "I have a memory problem here, should I suck on it or not?".

Comment: "everyone would stuff them directly into a long" - *not* everyone, for example the questioner didn't. My point is that the question is "why?", not "do I have a memory problem here?". So too much stuff on the side, along the lines of, "this does not cause a memory problem" becomes false information. It doesn't cause Clairevoire a memory problem, it might cause others a memory problem, and when that happens they should stuff their bits into a `char` rather than either a `bitset` or a `long`.

Answer (score 5):

The most likely explanation is that `bitset` is using a whole number of machine words to store the array.

This is probably done for memory bandwidth reasons: it is typically relatively cheap to read/write a word that's aligned at a word boundary. On the other hand, reading (and especially writing!) an arbitrarily-aligned byte can be expensive on some architectures.

Since we're talking about a fixed-sized penalty of a few bytes per `bitset`, this sounds like a reasonable tradeoff for a general-purpose library.

Comment: +1: Considering also that variables are also "word aligned", making the bitset shorter doesn't give any space saving.

Answer (score 1):

The memory system on modern machines cannot fetch anything else but words from memory, apart from some legacy functions that extract the desired bits. Hence, having the bitsets aligned to words makes them a lot faster to handle, because you do not need to mask out the bits you don't need when accessing it. If you do not mask, doing something like

```
bitset<4> foo = 0;
if (foo) {
    // ...
}
```

will most likely fail. Apart from that, I remember reading some time ago that there was a way to cramp several bitsets together, but I don't remember exactly. I think it was when you have several bitsets together in a structure that they can take up "shared" memory, which is not applicable to most use cases of bitfields.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same feature in Aix and Linux implementations. In Aix, internal bitset storage is char based:

```
typedef unsigned char _Ty;
....
_Ty _A[_Nw + 1];
```

In Linux, internal storage is long based:

```
typedef unsigned long _WordT;
....
_WordT            _M_w[_Nw];
```

For compatibility reasons, we modified Linux version with char based storage

Check which implementation are you using inside bitset.h

Comment: Clairvoire stated he/she is using VS2010. I checked the `<bitset>` header and for bitsets <= 32 bits the internal storage is an array of uint32_t. For bitsets >= 33 bits the internal storage is an array of uint64_t. The source looks like it would be easy to specialize for 8 or 16-bit internal storage but Dinkumware made a design decision not to in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Because a 32 bit Intel-compatible processor cannot access bytes individually (or better, it can by applying implicitly some bit mask and shifts) but only 32bit words at time.

if you declare

```
bitset<4> a,b,c;
```

even if the library implements it as char, `a`,`b` and `c` will be 32 bit aligned, so the same wasted space exist. But the processor will be forced to premask the bytes before letting bitset code to do its own mask.

For this reason MS used a `int[1+(N-1)/32]` as a container for the bits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it's using `int` by default, and switches to `long long` if it overflows? (Just a guess...)

Comment: I believe std::bitset is agnostic in that regard.  `sizeof(std::bitset<1024>)` for instance returns "128"

Answer (score 0):

If your std::bitset< 8 > was a member of a structure, you might have this:

```
struct A
{
  std::bitset< 8 > mask;
  void * pointerToSomething;
}
```

If bitset<8> was stored in one byte (and the structure packed on 1-byte boundaries) then the pointer following it in the structure would be unaligned, which would be A Bad Thing. The only time when it would be safe and useful to have a bitset<8> stored in one byte would be if it was in a packed structure and followed by some other one-byte fields with which it could be packed together. I guess this is too narrow a use case for it to be worthwhile providing a library implementation.

Basically, in your octree, a single byte bitset would only be useful if it was followed in a packed structure by another one to three single-byte members. Otherwise, it would have to be padded to four bytes anyway (on a 32-bit machine) to ensure that the following variable was word-aligned.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the point. You could use the same argument with `uint8_t` instead of `bitset<8>` and you would be arguing against putting `uint8_t` in structures.