# C++ writing byte to file

Tags: c++, binary, byte, bit

I am trying to write one byte to a file in C++. When I save it, is is 8 byte large, instead of 1 byte. How can I save exactly one byte?

```
ofstream binFile("compressed.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
bitset<8> a("10010010");
binFile << a;
```

Output of ls -la:

```
.rw-r--r-- name staff   8 B  Sat Dec  4 23:26:18 2021  compressed.bin
```

How can I small it down to one byte?

Comment: I think the posted duplicate [Why is std::bitset<8> 4 bytes big?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511355/why-is-stdbitset8-4-bytes-big) explains the problem, but does not answer the question asked here.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: Did you look at the contents of the file? Seeing what was output can be more informative than looking at just how much was output. *(A hex editor can be useful when you expect non-text data in the file. Or for a file this small, you could create another program that reads each byte from `compressed.bin`, converts to an integer, and streams that to the screen (don't forget a space between numbers).*

Comment: Oh.. and if the "another program" I mentioned reports that all (or most) of the integer values are in the range 32-126, consider converting to `char` instead, as that is the range of printable characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is designed for *formatted* output.

When writing strict binary, you should focus on member functions [`put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put) (for one byte) or [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) (for a variable number of bytes).

This will write your bitset as a single byte.

```
binFile.put( a.to_ulong() );
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what class bitset<size_t> is, but it seems to be creating a uint64_t underneath. Maybe the template parameter is for number of bytes instead of bits?

I can achieve a single byte binary file with

```
std::ofstream binFile("onebyte.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
uint8_t aByte = 0x77; // this is w in ASCII. Easy to see in a bin file
binFile << aByte;
```

Perhaps you need to cast bitset to a uint8_t?

Comment: *"Maybe the template parameter is for number of bytes instead of bits?"* -- [No](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset#Template_parameters).

Comment: *"Perhaps you need to cast bitset to a uint8_t?"* -- results in `error: invalid cast from type 'std::bitset<8>' to type 'uint8_t'`.

Comment: When you don't know what the subject of a question is, you should probably test your theory before answering (which is a good idea in any case). Even better, also look up [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: Ah, ok. You're using the STL bitset. So if you read the constructor here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset
You'll see it constructs a 64 (or 32byte depending on c++ version) if the size is less than 64.
So you want to either use put with .https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong as Drew Dormann described above, or static_cast that return from that to a uint8_t and use the stream operator. I think Drew gave a good explanation for why .put() is more appropriate

Comment: *"You'll see it constructs a 64 (or 32byte depending on c++ version) if the size is less than 64."* -- I see no such thing in the documentation. The only occurrence of `32` (and of `64`) on that page refers to the size of the parameter to a constructor, not to the size of the constructed object. That part of the documentation says that if you construct a `std::bitset<90>` from a 64-bit `unsigned long long`, then the low 64 bits are set from the `unsigned long long` and the remaining 26 bits are initialized to zeroes.